# how can I set label address in nasm

Tags: assembly, label, nasm, directive

how can I set label address in nasm?

putting org in other location doesn't make any difference

```
;;some loading and jumping code here

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    db 0x55
    db 0xaa
```

how can I treat my_label as 0x00?

org 0x00 acts like I put org directive on top of the code

```
    org 0x00
    my_label:
        %include 'main.s'
```

Comment: Right. Nasm accepts only one `org` directive. You may be able to declare a new `section` with `vstart=0`. See: http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1.3

Comment: @FrankKotler thanks. how can I select your reply as 'selected answer' for my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno. I suppose I can make it an "answer".

Right. Nasm accepts only one org directive. You may be able to declare a new section with vstart=0. See: nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1.3

Another approach might be to assemble "main.s" (any `org` you like) into, say "main.bin" and `incbin "main.bin"` where you want it.

Another approach would be to concatenate two separate files with `cat` or `copy /b`.

Happy bootin',
Frank